# Windows 10 boots instead of Linux Live USB (Ubuntu 15.10) - prior installed and deleted Ubuntu (GRUB is not functioning)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

Here is my problem I'm trying to solve in order to install Ubuntu 15.10.
I already tried a several BIOs options in order to get the USB Stick to work. Disabled/Enabled "Legacy USB Support", "UEFI Boot Support", "AHCI Mode".
My current boot priority looks like this (starts Windows 10):

> 1. USB FDD:
> 2. USB CD:
> 3. SATA CD: TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-L633J
> 4. NETWORK:
> 5. SATA HDD: SAMSUNG HM321HI
> 6. ubuntu

when I set ubuntu to a higher priority than the HDD the system boots with GRUB but it's broken anyways since GRUB appears to not function properly. I only get the message

> "*Grub Version*"
>
> [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supportet. For the First word, TAB list possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB list possible device/file completions. ]".

The ubuntu entry comes from a prior installation of Ubuntu. I deleted this instance of ubuntu by simply removing it's partition under windows. I think this corrupted the data for grub which causes it to not function properly. I also tried to boot from the USB on another PC which worked fine. What should I try to do next? Thanks in advance.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

First, ***know and understand your boot modes (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI)!*** If you're dual-booting, it's important that both OSes use the *same* boot mode. Fiddling with your boot-mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI) options in the firmware is more likely to cause problems than to solve them. If Windows was pre-installed on the system, it almost certainly used EFI/UEFI mode, so you should leave it set to boot in that way. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on what BIOS/CSM/legacy mode is on an EFI/UEFI-based computer.

To properly diagnose your problem, you should run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) on the computer. (Use an Ubuntu live CD/USB drive for this purpose.) This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`, which holds tons of information on things like installed boot loaders. You can post the file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post back here for help interpreting it. My *hunch* is that you installed an EFI-mode copy of GRUB (Ubuntu's default boot loader), then installed a BIOS-mode copy at some point. That's why launching the EFI-mode version (which is what shows up in the boot list as `ubuntu`) fails; it's expecting the EFI-mode configuration file but getting the BIOS-mode file, which it doesn't like. That's just a hunch, though.

If my hunch is correct, the solution is to install a working EFI-mode boot loader. There are two relatively easy ways to do this:

- Run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool *from an EFI-mode boot* of the Ubuntu installation image (in its "try before installing" mode). This should replace the GRUB configuration files, as well as GRUB itself. This approach often works, but if my hypothesis about what's causing the problem is wrong, it might not work at all.
- Download the CD-R or USB flash drive image of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a boot image from it. If it's currently enabled, disable Secure Boot. You can then boot from the rEFInd medium and test that you can boot both Ubuntu and Windows. If so, boot into Ubuntu and install the PPA or Debian-package version of rEFInd, which should then take over the duties normally performed by GRUB. This approach has the advantage of enabling you to test the solution (rEFInd) before installing it to your hard disk.

Comment: Hey Rob. Thanks for your help! I've read your article which made some aspects which might cause my problem a bit clearer. The problem I have with running your Boot Info Script is that I've got no chance to boot Ubuntu. I've created a Ubuntu live USB with Linux Live USB Creator first and did the same with UNetbootin after reading your article. Before using one of those programs I formatted the USB Drive as FAT32  but when I try to boot from this device (with the boot order as described in the opening post) Windows still boots right away. On another PC this USB stick works fine.

Comment: It should boot in the way it did when you first installed Ubuntu (although if that was in BIOS mode, perhaps not). On most computers, hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key brings up a boot menu that enables you to change the boot device. If you can't get this menu but can enter the firmware setup utility, look for options to set a "fast boot" mode (or words to that effect) and disable them; or for options to enable or disable USB support and be sure USB support is fully enabled.